# Facing problem with the statement inJDBC, while query produces correct results

Tags: jquery, postgresql, jdbc

I have a project where ,based on an already created postgresql database , I want to have some return statements to show some results and see if they matach the query results. The first question I need to do is show the final grade of a class for a student by using the course code and a unique number called am. I have run and tested the query and it works, I have used correct values, but still the Java code will not produce a correct result. Th query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT final_grade
FROM "Register"
JOIN "Student" USING (amka) 
WHERE am ='2020000158'
AND course_code ='ΑΓΓ 101';
```

and the parts of Java code that interest me are as follows:

```java
public void showGrades(String am, String course_code) {
    
    try {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
          
            ResultSet rst = st.executeQuery( "SELECT final_grade \r\n"
                                          + "FROM \"Register\" \r\n"
                                          + "JOIN \"Student\" USING (amka)  \r\n"
                                          + "WHERE am ='"+am+"'\r\n"
                                          + "AND course_code ='"+course_code.trim()+"';");  
            if(rst.next()) { 
            System.out.println("The final grade is: "+rst.getBigDecimal(1));
           }
            else
                System.out.println("Final grade not found!");
            
        rst.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    
}
```

and the main because that is where the menu for cases is:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        PhaseB phB = new PhaseB();
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            phB.dbConnect("localhost", "Project_2023", "postgres", "asdf2332fdsa"); // o kwdikos,einai apla palios pou thumamai 
            
            while(true) {
                phB.menu();
                int i = sc.nextInt();
                if(i==1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter A.M.: ");
                    String am = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter course code: ");
                    String course_code = sc.next();
                    phB.showGrades(am, course_code);
                }
                //else if(i==2) {
                    //System.out.println("Enter A.M.: ");
                    //String am = sc.next();
                    //System.out.println("Enter course code: ");
                    //String course_code = sc.next();
                    //System.out.println("Enter serial number: ");
                    //int serial_number = sc.nextInt();
                    //phB.changeGrades(am, course_code, serial_number); 
                //}
                else if(i==3) {
                    
                }
                else if(i==4) {
                    System.out.println("Enter A.M.:");
                    String am = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("The detailed grades for student with A.M.: '"+am+"' are:");
                    phB.showDetailedGrades(am);
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Also, the tables are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."Student"
(
    amka character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    am character(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    entry_date date,
    CONSTRAINT "Student_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (amka),
    CONSTRAINT "Student_am_key" UNIQUE (am),
    CONSTRAINT student_fkey1 FOREIGN KEY (amka)
        REFERENCES public."Person" (amka) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        NOT VALID
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."Student"
    OWNER to postgres;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."Register"
(
    amka character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    serial_number integer NOT NULL,
    course_code character(7) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    exam_grade numeric,
    final_grade numeric,
    lab_grade numeric,
    register_status register_status_type,
    CONSTRAINT "Register_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (course_code, serial_number, amka),
    CONSTRAINT "Register_course_run_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (course_code, serial_number)
        REFERENCES public."CourseRun" (course_code, serial_number) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT "Register_student_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (amka)
        REFERENCES public."Student" (amka) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        NOT VALID
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."Register"
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Can you help me resolve this issue?

From what I've understood, because I also don't get any stack trace, but the menu stops responding after picking the first choice, there is a problem with the String course_code and probably the white space that needs to be taken inbetween, e.g. 'ΑΓΓ 101'. When I hard coded them (the am String and the course_code String) inside the showGrades function everything worked perfectly. I also tried to to use prepareStatement but it was of no use.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint after the query and then run select *
from pg_stat_activity
in your database to see what the actual query was. Also, please attach the connection string

Comment: String am = sc.next(); shouldn't it be nextLine() or something?